# How to make modifications on a subset of elements in a list

Tags: java

oldUsers is just a subset of allUsers and all oldUsers are made in-active in the following list. The logic currently works, but I am iterating allUsers just to get the handle of oldUser every time, before I set the active flag to false. Is there a way to pull the appropriate record and make my modifications (oldUsers and allUsers is of type `Set<User>`)

```
for (User oldUser : oldUsers) {
    for (User  user : allUsers) {
        if (user.getId().equals(oldUser.getId())) {
            user.setActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i suppose the objects in oldUsers are copies of the objects in allUsers, cause if they are the same object you can update directly the users in oldUsers no?

Comment: oldUsers are not copies from allUsers, but they were constructed in a different piece of code and passed to this method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `oldUsers` contains copies or fresh instances of users, and you simply want to `setActive(false)` on those users in `allUsers` that have a matching id, then I suggest you **override the .equals (and .hash) methods of User based on the user id**. You could then do like this:

```
Set<User> toInactivate = new HashSet<User>(allUsers);
toInactivate.retainAll(oldUsers);
for (User u : toInactivate)
    u.setActive(false);
```

---

Another way (perhaps even more elegant) would be to store the users in a `Map<Integer, User>` mapping user ids to users. You could then simply do

```
for (int id : oldUsers.keySet())
    allUsers.get(id).setActive(false);
```

Comment: did you mean toInactivate.retainAll(oldUsers); (i.e. oldUsers and not oldUser)

Answer (score 1):

if objects in oldUser and in allUsers are the same instances, than you just change oldUser.
if not, you define hashcode and equals, and than do: `allUsers.retainAll(oldUsers)`. Thus you will get interception of these two Sets, which consist of allUser instances. allUser set, however, will be changed (it'll shrink).

Answer (score -1):

Define User.equals() such that it compares getId()s, and call List.indexOf(user).

Comment: So define hasCode() too, or change them to Maps.